# IE 7 issue : jquery click to edit Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

I have a Effect From my Previous post . It have a button . When I click it Create a Div having ability to click and Edit and rename the field . This effect works Great in all the Browsers bu no in IE7 . I am wondering why and if is there any way I can made this support by IE 7 .

[Here is Live demo in js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzKWD/8/)

My code :

**HTML**

```
<button id="createDiv">Start</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #createDiv, #results span { cursor: pointer; }
   #results div {
    background: #FFA;
    border: 1px solid;
   width:auto;
}
#results input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
.clickToCancleIcon{
float: right;

}

.new-folder{
height:30px; 
float:left;

 }
```

**JS**

```
    //  Call for document .onload event
       $(function() {
       //  Normal Click event asignement, same as $("#createDiv").click(function
       $("#createDiv").on("click", function(e) {
         //  Simply creating the elements one by one to remove confusion
          var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: "new-folder" }),  //  Notice, each child variable is   appended to parent

            newInp = $("<input />", { name: "inpTitle[]",style:"display:block ;float:left; border:solid 1px #fa9a34", type: "text", value: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-inp" }).appendTo(newDiv),

            newSpan = $("<span />", { id: "myInstance2",style:"display:none; float:left;", text: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-span" }).appendTo(newDiv),


            clickToCancle = $("<a />", { text: "X", class: "clickToCancleIcon" }).appendTo(newDiv),
           clickToEdit = $("<span />", { text: "Edit" , style:"float:right; margin:0px 5px;" ,



             class: "clickToEdit" }).appendTo(newDiv);


        //  Everything created and seated, let's append this new div to it's parent
        $("#results").append(newDiv);
    });

    //  the following use the ".delegate" side of .on
    //  This means that ALL future created elements with the same classname, 
    //    inside the same parent will have this same event function added
    $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
        //  This hides our span as it was clicked on and shows our trick input, 
        //    also places focus on input
        $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
    });
    $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
        //    also replaces text in span with new text in input
        $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
    });
    //  The following sures we get the same functionality from blur on Enter key being pressed
    $("#results").on("keyup", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  Here we grab the key code for the "Enter" key
        var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (eKey == 13) { // if enter key was pressed then hide input, show span, replace text
            $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it points to this line of code

```
var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: "new-folder" }),
```

change `class` to `"class"` with the quotes.

```
var newDiv = $("<div />", { "class": "new-folder" }),
```

and do the same with the other lines that have class.

Comment: I can confirm that is what's causing the problem. He's also done that on every variable definition that follows.

Comment: yeah ! working now perfectly in after I put this :) thank you So much

Answer (score 1):

IE7 doesn't like using property names without strings for some reason. See:

http://jsfiddle.net/teynon/26fe9/7/

```
    //  Call for document .onload event
$(function() {
        //  Normal Click event asignement, same as $("#createDiv").click(function
        $("#createDiv").on("click", function(e) {
            //  Simply creating the elements one by one to remove confusion
            var newDiv = $("<div />", { "class": "new-folder" }),  //  Notice, each child variable is appended to parent

                newInp = $("<input />", { "name": "inpTitle[]","style":"display:block ;float:left; border:solid 1px #fa9a34", "type": "text", "value": "Unnamed Group", "class": "title-inp" }).appendTo(newDiv),

                newSpan = $("<span />", { id: "myInstance2",style:"display:none; float:left;", text: "Unnamed Group", "class": "title-span" }).appendTo(newDiv),


                clickToCancle = $("<a />", { "text": "X", "class": "clickToCancleIcon" }).appendTo(newDiv),

                clickToEdit = $("<span />", { "text": "Edit" , "style":"float:right; margin:0px 5px;" ,"class": "clickToEdit" }).appendTo(newDiv);


            //  Everything created and seated, let's append this new div to it's parent
            $("#results").append(newDiv);
        });

        //  the following use the ".delegate" side of .on
        //  This means that ALL future created elements with the same classname, 
        //    inside the same parent will have this same event function added
        $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
            //  This hides our span as it was clicked on and shows our trick input, 
            //    also places focus on input
            $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
        });
        $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
            //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
            //    also replaces text in span with new text in input
            $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
        });
        //  The following sures we get the same functionality from blur on Enter key being pressed
        $("#results").on("keyup", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
            //  Here we grab the key code for the "Enter" key
            var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
            if (eKey == 13) { // if enter key was pressed then hide input, show span, replace text
                $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for giving full specification :) I understand now completely